# Concurrent usage of rdbms, write 4K rows without lockdown

Tags: postgresql, performance, concurrency, django, postgresql-performance

I am working on a django project using Postgresql. The use case is as follows:

A user needs to upload an excel (containing 2.5-4K rows) 2-3 times daily. There will be 100s of users (somewhere between 1100-1200).

Now, the issue is the app is taking 1.2-1.8 seconds to write the data in the db. During this time, anyone else viewing the webapp is seeing a "server busy" error.

How can I get around this issue, so that:
1. Write speed can improve 
2. Other users can use the webapp and maybe in worst case, we can also have concurrent uploading of excel possible?

Comment: Writers do not block readers in Postgres, so it's unclear to me why your application would "lock up" during that period. What exactly is your application doing when you get the "server busy"? Does the import use a lot of connections? Can you use the database from a SQL client during the import? Do you get any error messages in the Postgres logfiles or the logfile of your application? If yes, what are those errors? What technology is your application? Is it using a connection pool? If yes which one? If yes how many connections are configured? Does the import use the same connection pool?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name, I am studying the log and finding out the errors related to the same, will try to resolve the issue. Thanks a lot mate with your questions. I believe these questions would ideally help me find out the root cause. Thanks again (I can't upvote a comment, can I?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you understand.

1. PostgreSQL has `max_connections`. If that number is hit people won't be able to connect to the database. If your server is waiting you may get a *"server busy"* message or the like. As @a_horse_with_no_name suggests connection pooling may solve this problem.
2. You can speed up writes by batching them. When you convert from your "excel format" to SQL are you doing one insert, or one insert per row? Consider inserting into an unlogged table if you're inserting one row at a time, and then running a single `INSERT INTO SELECT` to UPSERT into the master.
3. You should also check out the [non-durability settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/non-durability.html) for faster writes

Comment: Thanks @Eavn. This was a great answer. Surely, I need to get my head rolled with te max_connection. It's not insert 1 row at a time, it's like read all rows and check their integrity, then upload at a go. It might take a bit more RAM, but about 4K rows won't matter much there. Will try to take care of the system now